# Imprimir la nota mayor del promedio entre 30 alumnos

Tags: php

Escribir un programa en PHP que cargue en un array

Tengo esto :

```
} 

for ($x=0;$x<count($valores);$x++)
```

Comment: No se quien te ayudará, pero eso me sueña a ejercicio del clase, la cuestión es que se ponen para que aprendas y avances en tu formación como profesional. Por cierto , no seré yo el que te dé votos negativos.

Comment: La comunidad está para ayudarte, no para hacerte la tarea, de menos tener la decencia de intentarlo, no puedes llamarte profesionista haciendo esto.

Comment: Muestra lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora. Tal y como está ahora la pregunta es demasiado amplia y seguramente acabe cerrada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
function MediaPositiva ($arr,$mediaFunc)
{
  $retArr = array();
  for ($i=0; $i <count($arr) ; $i++)
  {
    if($arr[$i] >$mediaFunc)
    {
      array_push($retArr,$arr[$i]);
    }
  }
  return $retArr;
}

$res = array();
$valores = array();
for ($x=0;$x<30;$x++)
{
    $num_aleatorio = rand(1,10);
    array_push($valores,$num_aleatorio);
  }

$media = array_sum($valores) / count($valores);

$res = MediaPositiva($valores,$media);
echo '<h4>Las notas mayores a '.$media.' son: </h4><br>';
$y = 1;
for ($i=0; $i <count($res) ; $i++)
{
  echo '<label>'.$y.'.-Esta nota es de:  '.$res[$i].'</label><br>';
  $y++;
}

echo '<h4>Se descartaron '.(count($valores) - count($res)).' notas</h4>';
 ?>
```

Te recomiendo que le metas más leña a la siguiente. No te olvides de marcar como correcta si te sirve.